# How To Convert C++ loops into C style loops?

Tags: c++, c, loops, code-translation

How can I translate a loop like the below one to C style?

```
for (auto element : vector) {
   Do_Somethin();
}
```

Comment: @JohnnyMopp It doesn't matter.

Comment: `Is there a tool`...

Comment: there is no `C` style for loop!!!!

Comment: Recommendation: Don't translate code from one language to another. Even when the code does have a more-or-less literal translation, it might not make sense overall in the context of the new program. Understand the observable behaviour of the original program and implement identical behaviour in the new language using the new language's idioms and following its best practices. Then exhaustively test both programs to ensure the observable behaviour is identical. To do this you need to understand both languages fairly well.

Comment: I have a tool which detect loop bounds only in C but the code is written in C++

Comment: You translate the loop by knowing what that loop means, and then implementing the same loop in the language you're translating to.  Look at it in the long run -- today it's the loop, tomorrow it will be something else that exists in C++ that doesn't exist in C.

Comment: "_I have a tool which detect loop bounds only in C but the code is written in C++_" - Is this limitation of the tool the reason you are translating the code? If so - don't! Drop that tool and get a tool suitable for analyzing C++ code.

Comment: Yes, do not write code so that it fits a third-party tool.  That tool you're using now, whatever it is, will probably not be able to detect lambda syntax, move assignment and move copy operations, etc.

Comment: `for (size_t index = 0; index < sizeof vector/sizeof *vector; index++) { do_somethin(vector[index]); }`

Comment: The tool analyze normal applications in C , my application is in C++ and here is the point

Comment: @HazemAbaza Then, drop that tool. It's not the correct tool.

Comment: @HazemAbaza -- C and C++ are two different languages.

Comment: @HazemAbaza -- But why do you need bounds analysis for a range-based `for`?  It already has built-in bounds analysis.

Comment: @HazemAbaza If you don't drop that tool, you'll be transforming the C++ program into C-ish looking code bit by bit. It'll be a horrible mess and noone will understand why you did what you did.

Comment: @HazemAbaza -- A lot of errors that would usually come with a C program, such as loop boundary errors, are easily alleviated in C++ by using range-base `for` loops, using algorithm functions instead of writing `for` loops, etc.  Thus you using such a tool for `C` programs makes very little, if any sense.

Comment: _Is there a way to use it for C++ code?_  **No.**  Ask the vendor of the tool if they have a similar tool but for C++.

Comment: but this is the only available tool. Re-implementing it would consume a lot of time

Comment: *but this is the only available tool* -- So I guess you will translate your C++ to C so that you can make use of this tool.  Otherwise what is there to discuss further?

Answer (score 5):

You'd start with converting it to a non-ranged-based for loop.

```
{
  auto&& range = Chains;
  using std::begin; using std::end; // possibly cbegin/cend
  auto it = begin(range); // possibly cbegin
  auto end = end(range); // possibly cend
  for(; it!=end; ++it) {
    auto block = *it;
    // body of loop
  }
}
```

then you tease apart each piece.

Start by deducing what the `auto` variables are.  Guess if you have to, then do a `static_assert( std::is_same_v< decltype(begin), your_guess > );` to confirm.  Once you have confirmed, replace.  DO NOT guess and swap in the type and assume "it compiles, I got it right"; that can lead to subtle bugs.

Then replace `begin` and `end` with an equivalent expression.  You'll have to do some research (it could be raw pointers into arrays, or it could be `.begin` methods, or it could be a free `begin` function in the namespace of the range expression).

What happens next depends on what your iterators are here.  Are they plain pointers?  If so, the problem is probably pretty easy.  If not, you have more work to do.

Finally, remove all references, and then tidy up.

Ideally you'd want to do each of these steps as a git commit with unit tests confirming no change of behavior.  You appear not to be qualified to make these changes without such testing.  That is ok, and the unit testing will have value.

---

Going the other way, there are C++ to C translators.  They will generate unreadable and unmaintainable code in practice.

But the output can be compiled by a C compiler.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, you can always exchange ranged-for for a classic for loop.**

For ranged-for to work, `Chains` must be of a type that implements an iterator interface, or must be an array.

If it's an array, you know what to do.

Otherwise, you can write the loop as:

```
for (auto it = Chains.begin(), end = Chains.end(); it != end; ++it)
{
   auto block = *it;
   Do_Somethin();
}
```

*(Though, possibly, you may need `cbegin()` if only a const interface is available and `begin()` has no `const` overload for some reason.)*

If the type of `Chains` supports random access with `operator[]`, you could also try something like this:

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < Chains.size(); ++it)
{
   auto block = Chains[i];
   Do_Somethin();
}
```

… though you'll need to look at the documentation to find out what `.size()` should actually be.

Now of course C doesn't have iterators, or `auto`, but then it doesn't have classes either. You can choose to substitute replacements for those features as well if you like.

Comment: Unless it's a random access container with `operator[]`.

Comment: @sweenish Well okay I suppose that would look a bit more C-like. But my point was that you'd still be using non-C features, like `operator[]`.

Comment: `C` does not have `auto` type. Also initialization in `c` used to takes place outside of loop